# select_related получить определенные поля

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

Подскажите как получить все поля в `Post` а у родителей только `slug`
У меня получиться что нужно в ручную прописывать все  поля для `Post` так как применил `only`:

```py
posts = Post.objects.filter(sub_post=self.object)\
        .select_related('sub_post__topics_category__category')\
        .only('sub_post__topics_category__category__slug',
              'sub_post__topics_category__slug', 'sub_post__slug')
```

поля `Post`:

```
('name', 'id', 'text', 'discussion', 'cat_post', 'top_post')
```

Есть ли способ применить only только к select_related не трогая содержимого пост ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select_related следует использовать для всей модели, а затем уже отфильтровать требуемые поля. Это будет работать:

```
Articles.objects.select_related('blog').only('blog__name', 'title', 'create_time')
```

[Оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35527474/19736488)

Comment: Вы раз просто в переводчик вбиваете исходный текст на английском без правок, то оставляйте хотя бы ссылку на оригинальный ответ...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35527474/19736488